# Quarkus File Upload results in 413

Tags: quarkus

I am trying to increase the max file size for upload. At the moment it is limited to 10MB and I cannot increase it.

I have already checked the Quarkus docs and other stackoverflow questions. The following quarkus settings are configured:

```
quarkus.http.limits.max-body-size: 30M
quarkus.http.limits.max-form-attribute-size: 30M
```

But every time I try to upload a file larger than 10MB it returns the error code `413`.

Comment: Is gzip enabled? if so: have you tried setting [`quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-resteasy-common_quarkus.resteasy.gzip.max-input)?

Comment: no, it's disabled

Comment: Curious... could you try setting the property anway?

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. a github-repository?

Comment: the gzip setting didn't work either...

Comment: found the solution. The problem was that our application received the call and then called another service, which returned the 413 but we couldn't see from which service the error was coming. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that our application received the call and then called another service, which returned the 413 but we couldn't see from which service the error was coming. So we added the limit-configs to the other service and it works